# ternary expression in ng-href

Tags: angularjs, html, ternary-operator

There's a complex(ish) ternary expression in a ng-href which just doesn't seem to work.

```
ng-href="item.hasTrailer ? 
'#/{{getTemplateName(routeParams.mainCategoryId).detail}}
/{{routeParams.mainCategoryId}}/{{routeParams.categoryId}} 
/{{item.trailer_media_uri[langCtrl.currentLanguage.isoCode]}}' : 
'#/{{getTemplateName(routeParams.mainCategoryId).detail}}
/{{routeParams.mainCategoryId}}/{{routeParams.categoryId}}
/{{item.media_uri}}'"
```

if I wrap the whole expression inside double curlies

```
 "{{item.hasTrailer ... item.media_uri}}'}}"
```

Angular throws lexerr with a message about a unnecessary quote. Shall I try to make it through ng-href (then please tell me the proper way/syntax), or shall I move this logic inside the controller of this page?

Comment: You need to include the whole ternary operation into `{{ ... }}`. Also your expression is, like you said, complex. Therefore place it inside your controller function. Code like this is hard to read.

Comment: I had that guess and tried it before. As I wrote in the original post that results in a Lexer Error:

[$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 18-73

Comment: Even if you could, don't, ewewew.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know, I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work:

```
ng-href="{{item.hasTrailer ? 
'#/' + getTemplateName(routeParams.mainCategoryId).detail
+ '/' + routeParams.mainCategoryId + '/' + routeParams.categoryId 
+ '/' + item.trailer_media_uri[langCtrl.currentLanguage.isoCode] : 
'#/' + getTemplateName(routeParams.mainCategoryId).detail
+ '/' + routeParams.mainCategoryId + '/' + routeParams.categoryId
 + '/' + item.media_uri}}"
```

It's crazy complicated :) I think you should place it in controller.I am also not sure if angular expressions can be multi-line.